# Reuse FAQ in multiple documents?

Tags: microsoft-word

I use MS Word 2016 and working with five different documents with two things in common, cover page and FAQ. All other content is different. If I want to update the FAQ, I don't want to update all five documents. What is the best solution?

My first guess is to have FAQ and cover sheets in separate documents and link them in each of the five documents. Is it the best solution? Have previously had problems with that links breaks (and I have to link them again) and that the documents do not updates when updating the linked document (eg FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

First, create your cover page and FAQ as two separate documents. Then, for each of the five documents, create a Master Document and insert the cover page and FAQ.

Here's how:

1. Create a new document.
2. Under the `View` tab click `Outline`.
3. Click `Show Document`.
4. Place the caret where you want to embed the cover page, click `Insert` and select the cover page file.
5. Do the same for the FAQ.

You've now created a master document with the cover page and FAQ as subdocuments. You can switch back to `Print Layout` view and edit your document. The cover page and FAQ are seamlessly integrated into your document and changes you make to them will be saved and reflected in the four other documents.